# How do I access a web server on the other end of an ethernet bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, bridge, forwarding

Sorry if this is a stupid question; I know very little about networking and I've been struggling to figure this out!

For a fun project, I'm trying to set up a vintage Mac as a web server (technically an Apple Lisa running MacWorks, but basically a Mac for all intents and purposes). The Lisa doesn't have an ethernet jack, so I'm using a [PISCSI](https://github.com/PiSCSI/piscsi/wiki/Dayna-Port-SCSI-Link) device that plugs into the system's SCSI port and uses the Raspberry Pi's ethernet port to serve as a bridge between the network in my house and the Lisa itself. From what I understand (I could be very wrong here) the Pi serves as a router for the traffic coming from the Lisa and thus I'm unable to access the Lisa's web server from any computers that are on my home network, but on the "outside" of the PISCSI bridge since the bridge assigns the Lisa an IP that's not recognized by the router in my house.

So my question consists of two parts:

1. Is my understanding of how this system works correct?
2. How do I go about sending the Lisa's IP address through the bridge so that I can access my web server from my laptop?

Once again, I know next to nothing about network stuff (forwarding ports on my router is just about the extent of my knowledge), so apologies if this is a really stupid/basic question!

Comment: After reading your question I don't know if your RPi is a bridge or a router because you employ both words and they don't mean the same. You should provide a schematic to help clarify things.